# Php: date +1 displays 1970

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I'm getting the output of:

```
Warning: strtotime() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\MindWeather\Assimilation\foreca_hourly.php on line 17


Today is 2014117, Tomorrow is 1970101
```

My code is:

```
$TodayIs = date('Ynd');
$nextdate = date('Ynd', strtotime($TodayIs,'+ 1 day'));
echo "<br><br> Today is $TodayIs, Tomorrow is $nextdate<br><br>";
```

I really don't expect to get a 1970-answer. It's supposed to display **"Today is 2014117, Tomorrow is 2014118"** instead of *"Today is 2014117, Tomorrow is 1970101"*

Comment: Read the warning, it says already what is wrong. Secondly, if you don't know the parameters for the function, read the [**documentation**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second parameter to [strtotime](http://www.php.net/strtotime) defaults to current time. So the following should produce desired result:

```
$nextdate = date('Ynd', strtotime('+1 day'));
// Today is 2014117, Tomorrow is 2014118
```

Comment: I see. But why does it return to 1970 something?

Comment: You know what [garbage in, garbage out](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_in,_garbage_out) means in programming, right?

Comment: Oh yes, that's gigo :)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make use of a [`DateTime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) Class ?

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime();
echo "Today is ".$date->format('Y/m/d');
$date->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
echo "<br>Tomorrow is ".$date->format('Y/m/d');
```

**OUTPUT :**

Today is 2014/01/17
Tomorrow is 2014/01/18

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
$TodayIs = date('Ynd');
$nextdate = date('Ynd', strtotime('+ 1 day'));
echo "<br><br> Today is $TodayIs, Tomorrow is $nextdate<br><br>";
```

PHPfiddle link: http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/bnf-scw

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$date = '2013-10-15';

$new_time = strtotime('+1 day', strtotime($date));

echo date('d-m-Y', $new_time); //displays 2013-10-16
```